# How to dynamically update a span with the value of a changing JavaScript Variable?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am working on a Javascript project where I have a variable `completedTasks` that changes dynamically due to many events.
The variable represents the count of completed tasks.
I want to display its value in a `<span>` element and have it automatically update whenever `completedTasks` changes.

```html
<span id="ischeck">Initial Value</span>
<script>
//completedTasks is a variable changing over time due to some events
let completedTasksArray = 0;
//I want the span to display the current value of completed Tasks without explicitly updating it in every part of the code
</script>
```

Is there any approach?

Comment: In which context and for which logic ? You must read  [SO guideline**S**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the case of a debugging context, you just have to add edge points upon your variable.

Comment: JS doesn't support watching a usual scoped variable's changes

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'some_value', {
  set(value) {
    console.log('some_value set to: ', value)
  }
});

some_value = 3

//some_value set to:  3

some_value = 2

//some_value set to:  2
```

Granted this works if your variable in global.

Answer (score 0):

You may utilize this vanilla JS solution that @twalow has suggested.

But if you want to dive deeper into reactive programming try this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-skkrjr) out

The snippets:

**TS**:

```
// Import stylesheets
import { interval, startWith, Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');

const subject = new Subject();

subject
  .pipe(
    tap((value) => {
      appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter ${value}</h1>`;
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

/**
 * pretending subject value changes
 */
interval(2000)
  .pipe(
    startWith(-1),
    tap(console.log),
    tap((value) => subject.next(value))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```